# select all when variable is empty or null else select values filtered

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-query-syntax

My linq query to summarize something like -

```
       string CustomerID;// can be "ALL" or any value

        var itemlist = ( from itmhstry in context.ItemHistories
               join itm in context.Items on itmhstry.ItemID equals itm.ItemID into itm_join
               where itmhstry.CustomerID == CustomerID
.......................)
```

and query goes on to select values needed

here how to select all values (like select * >> without filter) when  `CustomerID` value is ALL/NULL.? How to frame the where clause for this purpose?

I can rewrite same query with if else to have two different queries to handle this issue but is there any simpler way to do?

Comment: I dont't get it sorry...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var itemlist = from itmhstry in context.ItemHistories
               join itm in context.Items on itmhstry.ItemID equals itm.ItemID into itm_join
               where string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomerID) || 
                     (CustomerID == "ALL") ||
                     (itmhstry.CustomerID == CustomerID)
```

If `CustomerID` is empty or null or "ALL", then either the first or the second predicate in the `where` clause evaluate to `true` and no filtering is applied. If `CustomerID` is not empty AND not null AND not "ALL", then you end up with the initial query.